# Why use array of char instead of int for bitsets in C++

Tags: c++, bitset

For a project I'm working on I need to create my own implementation for a bitset. I've taken a look at the STL library to see how they handle this and looked at a few other things online. It seems like it's pretty standard to use a char array. Is there a reason why everyone uses char arrays instead of the integer type?

Comment: as I remember it `unsigned char` is often used.  It is the equivalent of a byte.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why isn't `std::bitset` or `boost::dynamic_bitset` suitable?

Comment: For `std::bitset`, both GCC and VC++ appear to use an array of `unsigned long`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply because a `char` in C++ is a single byte, (or at least, it's guaranteed by the C++ standard to be less than or equal in size to `int` or `short`) whereas the size of an `int` is usually larger than a byte.  (It's usually 32-bit, or 4-bytes, on most machines these days.)  Since a single byte is the smallest addressable unit of data a computer can process, it's natural to use arrays of `char`s when working with individual bits.  If you used `int`, for example, then you would waste significant space for any number of bits that is not a multiple of `sizeof(int)`, but with a byte array you waste the least amount of space possible.

Comment: As a matter of fact, char, signed char and unsigned char are **guaranteed** to be one byte by the C++ standard. Although how many bits that is is implementation-defined :)

Comment: Of course, the definition of 'byte' is not always 8 bits. I once wrote C for an 8-bit PIC where char was a 4-bit (byte) and int was 8-bit (two bytes).

Comment: @Tergiver: C obviously wasn't the language you used, because neither 4 nor 8 bits are enough for `char` and `int` types, respectively, the way standard defines them.

Comment: Yes, a signed char and unsigned char are guaranteed to be one by by the C++ standard, but they redefine 'byte' to be the size of a char. So a C++ byte can be 12 bits...

Answer (score 1):

Char is (usually) the smallest unit of bits that a microprocessor can manipulate. If you're creating an object that works with arbitrary numbers of bits, it makes sense to use an array of the smallest unit. That way you always use the fewest units possible.

If you need a non-arbitrary-sized bitset and the processor has a native type large enough to contain it, use an N-bit type. It will be more efficient than an array.